# How to remove object and then appear again on restart click ?Corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want object disappear on collision and then again appear when restart button is clicked. Here is my code :)

```
function touchRestart(event)
  if event.phase=="began" then
    print('foo')
  end
end
restart:addEventListener("touch",touchRestart)

function onLocalCollision(raketa,event)
  if event.phase=="began" then
    if event.object1.myName=="meteor" and event.object2.myName=="raketa" then
      score=score -1
      scoreNumber.text = score
      restart.isVisible=true
    end
  end
end
raketa.collision = onLocalCollision
Runtime:addEventListener("collision",raketa)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be pretty easy.

Make your `object.alpha = 0` , then when you click the restart button make the `object.alpha = 1`

Hope that helps.